# Python: Faster way to call functions in loops

Tags: python, arrays, function, loops

I have a python function f1(x) that does some processing to global variables and does not return any value. I have a array containing some strings and I want the function to run on each of them. Is there any fast way rather than looping?

```
def f1(x):
  ....

arr=['abc', 'def', 'ghi', ...] # It has 5000 strings

for i in arr:
  f1(i)
```

Can anyone help speed this up?

Comment: Looping through 5000 elements takes milliseconds at worst. If this code takes a long time to run, this isn't your bottleneck. Use a profiler.

Comment: One way to speed up is to avoid function calls in a loop. You can either place the code of the function inside the loop or pass the array to the function.

Comment: How long does your function take to run?  You call your function serially.  So it takes approximately 5000 times longer than calling the function once. If you function run for a long time, you may consider rewrite it or use multiprocessing.

Comment: @Ronald what makes you say that? The call itself isn't taxing. It's the algorithm/the logic behind it which is taxing. Just moving the logic around will not have any significant impact on the execution speed.

Comment: I based it on this article: https://nyu-cds.github.io/python-performance-tips/04-functions/

Comment: I think the question is how function `f1` can be made faster. But this is out of scope of the OP's question.

Comment: @AnsFourtyTwo, you are correct. Kunjal Shah, you should show the f1 function, so as to get what do you wanna do